# JavaScript, How to sort array by two sub index

Tags: javascript, sorting

am trying to sort xy coordinates on both sub index it once mean row column Asc order. i have sorted coordinates data via Y but when i sort that data again via X then i lost Y order , so any idea how to do it?

what i have done

example: my raw coordinates xy data

```
var cxray = [ [450,13],[455,12],[454,12],[451,12],[452,13],[453,12], [450,12],[453,13],[454,13],[450,13],[452,12],[455,13],];
```

my single index sorting function

```
 this.ray_isort = function(data,i){
    data.sort( function( a, b ,sindex=i){if ( parseFloat(a[sindex]) == parseFloat(b[sindex]) ) return 0;return parseFloat(a[sindex]) < parseFloat(b[sindex]) ? -1 : 1;});
    return data;
  };
```

Fiddle Link : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lkv2gzf/)

currently when i sort it with one index i get output

> ```
> 0  451,12
> 1  454,12
> 2  450,12
> 3  453,12
> 4  455,12
> 5  452,12
> 6  452,13
> 7  453,13
> 8  454,13
> 9  450,13
> 10  450,13
> 11  455,13
> ```

my goal is to get

```
0  450,12
1  451,12
2  452,12
3  453,12
4  454,12
5  455,12
6  450,13
7  451,13
8  452,13
9  453,13
10  454,13
11  455,13
```

Comment: `array.sort((a,b)=> a[0]-b[0] || a[1] - b[1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[1] - b[1]` will sort the array using the second items of each array.

If they're equal, the result will be `0` and thus the `a[0] - b[0]` part will be executed and will sort the array using the first items.

```js
const cxray = [ [450,13],[455,12],[454,12],[451,12],[452,13],[453,12], [450,12],[453,13],[454,13],[450,13],[452,12],[455,13],];

console.log(cxray.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1] || a[0] - b[0]));
```

Comment: Please add explanation as you are answering for readers and not just OP

Answer (score 1):

```
cxray.sort(([ax,ay],[bx,by])=>ay-by||ax-bx);
```

Simply sort after y first. If ay equals by, ay-by will be 0, so thanks to the or operator it will be then sorted after x.